# Share Labels to Ignore Questions?

Tags: feature-request

I have a very long list of ignored labels in SO:

> windows mac c# java javascript optimization iphone django sql c++ c
>   php html android jquery flash facebook .net actionscript visual-studio
>   windows-7 windows-mobile windows-services windows-phone-7 safari css
>   ...
>   ...
>   perl ajax google-chrome jsp citrix paypal adobe git groovy
>   iphone-sdk-4.0 iphone-sdk-3.0 dns flex hosting blackberry ipad qt qt4
>   forum

I am quite lazy to update this so SO is becoming quite unreadable currently, it contains a massive amount of stuff that I would like to filter away.

I would like to share this with my friends because it gets old very soon and I think there may be someone already with good ignore -lists. Is there some way to share ignores?

Comment: Can't help but think it might be easier to just list the stuff you *are* interested in...

Comment: @NineShogsShogging: for that I use specific SE sites, rarely using SO currently. The labels are a way to communicate, I cannot understand why not make some sharing for them. I would like to have different label modes -- like when doing XYZ thing, I just want to get ZYX distraction away etc. Currently, it is just a mess -- would help a lot to filter stuff out also by killing stuff...and organizing that process, not sure how to do currently. It is often easier to filter out junk, rather than filter out "goodies".

Answer (score 2):

While this still seems a bit... crazy...

...the solution is trivial: share 'em like you're sharing yours with all of us right now! Tags are just words, bits of text separated by spaces. You can select, copy, and paste them en masse.

If your friend wants to add your ignored - or favorite - tags to his own preferences, all he need do is paste them into the respective input field:

[image: screenshot of the tag preference inputs]

...and click the appropriate "Add" button.

---

I'd like to add here that I have NO favorite or ignored tags. Instead, I build filters "on the fly" to suit my needs - usually starting with a root tag and then refining by clicking one of the related tags in the right-hand sidebar, repeating as necessary until I've reduced the list of questions to something manageable. But then again, I tend to flip between different sets of technologies fairly often; YMMV...